# How to solve this visual studio query error?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am using SQL server in Visual Studio 2015. I can't seem to execute a query on my database. I have also tried to restart my visual studio and refresh my database. These are the errors that appear.

**Microsoft Visual studio error that appears on a dialog box:**

> An exception has been encountered.  This may be caused by an
>   extension. You can get more information by examining the file
>   \AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ActivityLog.xml

**Error that appears when I try to execute a query:**

> An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: Horizontal
>   scroll unit should be greater than zero.

Answer (score 0):

I get this issue quite often.
Updating SSMS or Restarting the system does solves the issue for me.